# 'For' loop in Swift error?

Tags: swift, for-loop

Here is my 'for' loop:

```
let size:Int = 64
for var z = 0;z < size;++z{    
}
```

I think the syntax is right, but the compiler always tells me:

[image]
is it bug or something?

*ps: Xcode version6.1.1*

Comment: Your code sample works for me in a Playground. I'm guessing that you have something messed up somewhere else, but its only getting caught here.

Comment: I annotated all other code and the error is still there @cjwirth

Comment: Your code should trigger a warning; [that's not how to do a for loop in Swift](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ControlFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH9-ID121).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your screenshot, it looks like you're inserting code in the body of a class directly. You should move it to, e.g., the body of a method. Then it will compile fine.

I would still encourage you to insert spaces after `;` and `:` for readability, however.